# Third party apps in Apple Watch without internet

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-3

I'm trying to compare the possibilities of use beetween Apple WatchOS and Android Wear when it comes to using them without the phone nearby. And without conection to internet (Wi-Fi).

I own a Android Wear and have tested the possibilities but cant get an Apple Watch and all the info I can find is this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205547
It says that with wifi you can: Use apps that support Wi-Fi. But what does it mean to support Wi-Fi? Does that mean third party apps cannot be used without internet in any case?

Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party apps can run on watchOS without a network connection even if the Watch is not connected to the paired iPhone.
That piece of documentation you linked is only showing which **system apps** can be used without being connected to an iPhone with/without network connection.

If your watchOS app is not network based, it can fully function even when the Watch is not connected to the iPhone and there are no known Wifi networks available.